# MS SQL Server - Need to transform similar rows into old and new values

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which looks like so

[image]

I need to transform it (Name being the key) to show just the changed values with their field name like so

[image]

Is this even possible via SQL?

Update: Sorry, I should of mentioned that each entry will be timestamped, so old and new will be based upon the date

Comment: Which value is `old` and which `new`? Do you have an order column or the new value is simply the greater value?

Comment: Sorry, I should of mention that each entry will be timestamped, so old and new will be based upon the date

Comment: You have based your question on a very clean set of rows - where every name has 2 and only 2 rows. What happens when there are 3 rows per name? 10 rows per name? And go update your sample data with timestamps so that it is clear what you have.